# Access a HTTP GET Request via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http, header

Basically I have written an AJAX script using pure javascript and I have a script that basically takes in a HTTP GET REQUEST.

e.g. script.php?id=2

I want to use this id within javascript so it can be sent via AJAX to return data from my database.

How can I access the id value. It should be possible as the value should be present within the headers of the loaded page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`window.location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location), the search property has the vales you're interested in.

This function will return an object which has all the variables as keys:

```
function queryVars() {
    var q = window.location.search.slice(1).split(/&/g);
    var ret = {};
    for (i=0;i<q.length;i++) {
        var item = q[i].split(/=/);
        ret[item[0]]=item[1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

From your page you could use it like this:

```
var myquery = queryVars();
window.alert(myquery.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be just what you're looking for:

http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: Would it also be possible by passing it as a parameter using the body onload() event. e.g. <body onload="processAjax('2')">...</body>???

Comment: @DanielWest You could also just write the value directly into some in page JavaScript using PHP: `<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>`.

Comment: The url is available everywhere you can use javascript (the answer is yes). However, it's better to use a javascript framework like jquery (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to make sure you're code is cross platform compatible.

Comment: @robertc - This may be easier, I would be able to control if the javascript was executed depending on whether a value was given a lot easier.

Comment: @Andras - Does JQuery provide an easy way to obtain the URL Parameters?

Comment: @Daniel jquery doesn't provide such a method. You can however implement it for your pages http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html